# How to split values on same row into individual rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has rows with a index of a date and 3 numbers in columns for each date. e.g.:

```
Date 02/21 | 3 | 4 | 2
Date 03/21 | 2 | 5 | 7
Date 04/21 | 5 | 4 | 2
```

I want to turn this dataframe so that each number is in its own row assigned to its indexed date e.g.:

```
Date 02/21 | 3
Date 02/21 | 4
Date 02/21 | 2
Date 03/21 | 2
Date 03/21 | 4
Date 03/21 | 7
Date 04/21 | 5
Date 04/21 | 4
Date 04/21 | 2
```

Any idea how I can transform my dataframe into this? The data is in a spreadsheet so I know how to load, but it's just transforming into the layout below that and I don't know how to do.

Comment: Have you tried something already? If yes, could you please show us in your question.

Comment: I havent tried anything other than the melt method shown below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to achieve this -

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = ['02/21','03/21','04/21']
>>> c1 = [3,2,5]
>>> c2 = [4,5,4]
>>> c3 = [2,7,2]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':d,'Col1':c1,'Col2':c2,'Col3':c3})

>>> df
    Date  Col1  Col2  Col3
0  02/21     3     4     2
1  03/21     2     5     7
2  04/21     5     4     2

>>> pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Date'],value_vars=['Col1','Col2','Col3']).sort_values(by=['Date','variable'])
    Date variable  value
0  02/21     Col1      3
3  02/21     Col2      4
6  02/21     Col3      2
1  03/21     Col1      2
4  03/21     Col2      5
7  03/21     Col3      7
2  04/21     Col1      5
5  04/21     Col2      4
8  04/21     Col3      2
>>>
```

Comment: This is great, thank you so much. Just a couple question to aid my understanding: How does  the new df know to call the columns 'variable' and 'value' with out defining it in the code?

Comment: Thats the default column names give to `id_vars` and `value_vars` , you can change them using `var_name` and `value_name` respectively. The default values are provided under documentation

Answer (score 0):

You want to 'unpivot' your table.  Pandas can do that with the melt() method: https://dfrieds.com/data-analysis/melt-unpivot-python-pandas.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler implementation so that you can read rows from your spreadsheet into a dataframe and dont have to type values manually. I have typed dataframe values manually as a sample but that can be replaced with code to read rows from your spreadsheet

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df=pd.DataFrame([['Date 02/21 | 3 | 4 | 2'],['Date 03/21 | 2 | 5 | 7'],['Date 04/21 | 5 | 4 | 2']], columns=['a'])
>>> df
                        a
0  Date 02/21 | 3 | 4 | 2
1  Date 03/21 | 2 | 5 | 7
2  Date 04/21 | 5 | 4 | 2
```

Split the columns on a specified delimiter(|)

```
>>> df2=pd.DataFrame(list(df.a.str.split('|')), columns=[1,2,3,4])
>>> df2
             1    2    3   4
0  Date 02/21    3    4    2
1  Date 03/21    2    5    7
2  Date 04/21    5    4    2
```

Unpivot

```
>>> df3=df2.melt(id_vars=[1])
>>> df3
             1  variable value
0  Date 02/21          2    3
1  Date 03/21          2    2
2  Date 04/21          2    5
3  Date 02/21          3    4
4  Date 03/21          3    5
5  Date 04/21          3    4
6  Date 02/21          4     2
7  Date 03/21          4     7
8  Date 04/21          4     2
```

Concatenate columns with the required delimiter for final output

```
>>> df4=pd.DataFrame(df3[1]+"|"+df3['value'])
>>> df4
                 0
0  Date 02/21 | 3
1  Date 03/21 | 2
2  Date 04/21 | 5
3  Date 02/21 | 4
4  Date 03/21 | 5
5  Date 04/21 | 4
6   Date 02/21 | 2
7   Date 03/21 | 7
8   Date 04/21 | 2
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.